# 'app-layout' is not a known element: how to share Component with different Modules

Tags: angular, angular6

My application was working fine until I decided to go with lazy loading:

So, my shared component looks like this:

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
export interface FormModel {
    captcha?: string;
  }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './app-layout.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-layout.css']

})
export class FullLayoutComponent {

}
```

app-layout.component.ts

I am using this component in my Another component say school-home.component.html like this:

```
<app-layout>
</app-layout>
```

and it was working fine until I created a Module school-home.module.ts like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SchoolhomeRoutingModule } from './school-home.routing.module';
import { SchoolHomeComponent } from './school-home.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SchoolhomeRoutingModule, FormsModule, ModalModule ],
  declarations: [SchoolHomeComponent]
})
export class SchoolhomeModule {}
```

Now, I get this error:

```
app-layout' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-layout' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-layout' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<app-layout>
```

If I try to add this component to school-home module:

This happens:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type FullLayoutComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and SchoolhomeModule! Please consider moving FullLayoutComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and SchoolhomeModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes FullLayoutComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and SchoolhomeModule.
```

I am unable to get from error about what implementation is required. Please suggest some workaround.

Comment: 2 components are in the same moule or different?

Comment: I have mentioned only one component i.e. FullLayout in app.module and in SchoolhomeModule, fullLayout and Schoolhome both are declared.

Comment: Your 2 component in 2 modules that's why this error occured.

Comment: You cannot declare 2 components in 2 modules. Declare in App.module and use it everywhere or declare in child module and export the component, then Import the module in app.module.ts

Comment: @jay where is applayout component  imported?

Comment: Agreed and understand, but when I keep this in app.module root level module I get this error. app-layout' is not a known element

Comment: You need to declare under declaration section in app.module.ts. remove from other module declaration

Comment: @Asanka It was imported in both root level and component level module but now I have removed from component level, but in this case component is not recognizing it

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Yes, it was exactly there until I created module for component level for lazy loading.

Comment: Follow the approach 1 from @Gautam, Create FullLayoutModule, declare FullLayoutComponent. Export it. Import the FullLayoutModule in AppModule and  SchoolhomeModule. This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**: 
First remove declaration of FullLayoutComponent from SchoolhomeModule.
Then create a module file for app-layout component and in that export your component like this.

`exports: [
        FullLayoutComponent
    ]`

After that import the module in SchoolhomeModule import section.

**You need to import module not component in this scenario**

**Approach 2**: You need to move FullLayoutComponent to a higher hierarchy module that imports AppModule and SchoolhomeModule

This is because both of your component are not under same module so your  SchoolhomeModule cannot get reference to FullLayoutComponent

Comment: Got your point, I was unable to fully understand the error message. Though it is pretty much clear. Let me implement the first approach.

Comment: I have mentioned it like this in index.ts file for that app-layout component export * from './app-layout.component';

Comment: isn't it serve the purpose?

Comment: @Jay In this case you can define route in your parent module and this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Import your module which contains the FullLayoutComponent to the SchoolhomeModule.

```
imports: [layoutModule]
```

And In the module which contain the FullLayoutComponent add the exports as **Gautam** says.

```
exports: [ FullLayoutComponent]
```